# Conditionals don't work with module values

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, conditional-statements

I am making a simple banker minigame. Just deposit and withdraw money. I am working with 3 modules and 1 main file (bank.py).

money.py

```
bank_balance = 500.00*100
wallet_balance = 500.00*100
```

bank_deposit.py

```
import money

def bank_deposit():

    while True:
        try:
            deposit = float(input("Deposit: "))
            if deposit <= money.wallet_balance and deposit > 0:
                print(f"Deposited ${deposit}!")
                break
            elif deposit == 0:
                print("You can't deposit $0!")
                continue
            elif deposit < 0:
                print("How are you supposed to deposit a negative ammount of money?\nC'mon, try again!")
                continue
            else:
                print(f"You haven't got enough money in your pockets! You only have {round(money.wallet_balance/100, 2)}.")
                continue
        except ValueError:
            print("Input must be a valid number!")


    money.bank_balance += deposit*100
    money.wallet_balance -= deposit*100

    print(f"Bank account balance: {round(money.bank_balance/100, 2)}")
    print(f"You have now ${round(money.wallet_balance/100, 2)} in your pockets.")
```

bank_withdraw.py

```
import money

def bank_withdraw():

    while True:
        try:
            withdraw = float(input("Withdraw: "))
            if withdraw <= money.bank_balance and withdraw > 0:
                print(f"Withdrawed ${withdraw}!")
                break
            elif withdraw == 0:
                print("You can't withdraw $0!")
                continue
            elif withdraw < 0:
                print("How are you supposed to withdraw a negative ammount of money?\nC'mon, try again!")
                continue
            else:
                print(f"You haven't got enough money in your bank account! You only have {round(money.bank_balance/100, 2)}")
                continue
        except ValueError:
            print("¡Input must be a valid number!")


    money.wallet_balance += withdraw*100
    money.bank_balance -= withdraw*100

    print(f"Bank account balance: {round(money.bank_balance/100, 2)}")
    print(f"You have now ${round(money.wallet_balance/100, 2)} in your pockets.")
```

bank.py

```
import money, bank_deposit, bank_withdraw

print("Welcome to The Bank. Please, sit down. How may I serve you?\n")

print("1. I want to check my balance.")
print("2. I want to make a deposit.")
print("3. I want to make a withdraw.")
print("4. I've changed my mind (leave).")

leave_bank = False

while True:
    try:
        while True:
            banker_ans = int(input("\nChoose an option (1/2/3/4): "))

            if banker_ans == 1:
                print(f"Your bank account holds actually ${round(money.bank_balance/100, 2)}.") # Las cantidades están *100.
                print(f"And if you can see, there is ${round(money.wallet_balance/100, 2)} in your wallet.")
                print("\nIs there anything else I may help you with?")
                continue

            if banker_ans == 2 and money.wallet_balance < 0:
                print("\nI'm sorry. But you don't have any money to deposit")
                continue

            if banker_ans == 2:
                bank_deposit.bank_deposit()
                print("\nIs there anything else I may help you with?")
                continue

            if banker_ans == 3 and money.bank_balance < 0:
                print("\nI'm sorry. But your bank account is empty.")
                continue

            if banker_ans == 3:
                bank_withdraw.bank_withdraw()
                print("\nIs Anything else I may help you with?")
                continue

            if banker_ans == 4:
                print("Thank you for your visit. Please, come back soon!")
                leave_bank = True
                break

            else:
                print("Input a number from 1 to 4. Then click intro button.")
                continue

        if leave_bank:
            break

    
    except ValueError:
        print("First input a number, so THEN press the enter button.")
```

The issue is with the last one. If you for example deposit your total and leave $0 in your wallet. If you press deposit (2), you will get into an endless loop. It's supposed to don't allow the user to press the 2nd option if there is no money in the wallet (and money.wallet_balance < 0). Anyone can explain to me what am I doing wrong?

Also if anyone can explain to me the solution or how to fix it, I would be really grateful.

PS: Same happens for the 3rd option if there is no money in the bank and you want to withdraw.

Comment: You don't need all those `continue` statements. Loops automatically continue unless the `while` condition is false or you `break`.

Comment: You mean in all 3 modules?

Comment: Why do you need nested loops in `bank.py`? Just use a single loop, and break out of it when they enter option 4

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Comment: I am using many loops to manage exceptions.

Comment: The problem is that your condition is `money.wallet_balance < 0`. If the wallet is empty, the value will be exactly 0, not less than 0. Use `<= 0` to include this case.

Comment: Ah ok. So it's just a logical fail. I've tried and it worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Where you have > or < put = like >= or <= respectively.

bank_withdraw.py - lines 8 and 14

bank_deposit.py - lines 8 and 14

bank.py - lines 24 and 33

Comment: How would this help?